# It's true that a valuation ring $R$ in the quotient field of a normal ring $A$ contain $A$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

Let $A$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra ($k$ algebraically closed) of dimension one, integrally closed in its quotient field $K$. Let $R\subseteq K$ be a valuation ring. It's true that $A\subseteq R$ ?

Thank you!

Comment: @user26857 A must be a domain as it is contained in a field: its quotient field!

Comment: Right, maybe OP missed some words.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to write that A is a domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Let $A=k[x]$ be the ring of univariate polynomials with coefficients in $k$. Then $K=k(x)$ is the field of rational functions, and $A$ is integrally closed in $K$. The valuation ring known as the "place at infinity"
$$
R=\left\{\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\in K\,\bigg\vert\,\deg p(x)\le \deg q(x)\right\}
$$
is a DVR in $K$. Clearly it does not contain $A$.

Comment: The definition Jyrki gives for $v_\infty$ requires $p\neq 0$. For $p=0$ the map $v_\infty$ is defined to be equal to $\infty$. Nothing to check here. Moreover: the valuation ring of $v_\infty$ does not contain $k[x]$ but $k[x^{-1}]$. The latter is a polynomial ring too, and $v_\infty$ ist just the $x^{-1}$-adic valuation from that point of view.

Comment: @user26857: Sorry about creating confusion. I ignored the problem with $p=0$ as I was concentrating on the DVR as opposed to the valuation. Thanks to Hagen for clarifying.

Comment: @user26857: Usually when extending the degree function to zero, you set $\deg 0 = -\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

By [Krull-Akizuki theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%E2%80%93Akizuki_theorem) every valuation ring containing a Dedekind domain is a DVR. If take $R$ a valuation ring which is not a DVR you can conclude.

An explicit example: let $L$ be a field, $k=L(Y)$, and $A=k[X]$. Then $K=k(X)=L(X,Y)$ and now consider for $K$ a [non-noetherian valuation ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/693021/121097).