# on the definition of noetherian scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition, schemes

The definition of noetherian scheme I have is that it can be covered by a fintie number of affine open subsets, where each of the affine open subset is the spectrum of a noetherian ring.  I was curious is this equivalent (or implies?) to the topological space of the scheme being a noetherian topological space? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Noetherian schemes are always noetherian as a topological space, but the converse is false in general. To see that, pick some non-noetherian valuation ring  [(see here for examples)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363166/examples-of-non-noetherian-valuation-rings) and consider the corresponding affine scheme.

Why does the implication hold? If a space $X$ is the union of finitely many noetherian subspaces $X_1,\dots,X_r$, then the space $X$ is noetherian itself and you can cover your noetherian scheme by finitely many noetherian spaces as the spectrum of a noetherian ring is noetherian.